# Possible to write 'try now' functionality in RAML?

Tags: raml

I'm playing around with RAML to document our API.  I've found a rather simple command line app that will generate HTML from a RAML specification.
[html2raml](http://raml2html.leanlabs.io/documentation)

The output is really clean and I like the style and simplicity of it, but it lacks a 'try now' functionality that can be seen in Swagger or other systems.

My question is, is it possible to write 'try now' functionality in the RAML code or is it something that is implemented by the compiler?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is implemented by the tool.

You can try this one, that has the try now functionality: https://anypoint.mulesoft.com